# How to remove round edges in square markers of matplotlib scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was generating a scatter plot with matplotlib using very small marker sizes. I used

```
figure(figsize=(3,2),dpi=1000)
i = np.arange(1,100)
x = i * 3.1426 / np.max(i)
y = np.sin(x)
s = 1/i
print(s)
scatter(x/10,y, marker='s', s=s)
```

[image]
If you look closely, you see the marker is actually never really squared, but has round edges. So, if you use small marker sizes, the markers become actually circles. Is that intended? My question is: How can I remove the round edges and have the marker really squared for all sizes?

Comment: Have you tried using the markers API with just a four-sided polygon? https://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/markers_api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove edgecolors, using `edgecolors='none'`

```
plt.scatter(x/10,y, marker='s', s=s, edgecolors='none')
```

Gives:

[image]

Note: You might have to set the size again as without edgecolors, the markers gets thinner.